# Pseducode Requirement

Tags: sql, database

I require Pseducode for the below mentioned code. I am not able to understand this code. Please help me out it. Thanks in advance.

```
select E.Pan,E.AST_YR
  from prd_ods_itb.ast_tt_elgble_cases E
 where E.Faceless_Flag = 'Y'
 and E.Jur_To_Faceless_Conv_Flag is null
   and 0 = (select count(1)
              from prd_ods_itb.com_tt_notices_details D, prd_ods_itb.com_tt_send_email S
             where S.Notice_Id = D.seq_no
              and D.Section_Code = '142(1)'
               and D.Mode_Of_Selection = 'S'
               and D.Document_Number <> 'DRAFT'
               and D.Status = '3'
               and S.Comm_Type_Flag = 'O'
               and D.Bpm_Request_Id = E.bpm_request_id
               and exists (select 1
                      from prd_ods_itb.com_tt_send_email n
                     where n.notice_id = s.notice_id
                       and n.comm_type_flag = 'I'))
   and 0 <> (select count(1)
               from prd_ods_itb.com_tt_notices_details D
               where D.Section_Code = '142(1)'
                and D.Mode_Of_Selection = 'S'
                and D.Document_Number <> 'DRAFT'
                and D.Status = '3'
                and D.Bpm_Request_Id = E.bpm_request_id)
    and E.assessment_status <>'C'
```

Comment: Hi - what, precisely, do you not understand about it?

Comment: I am not able to understand what is happening in this code. Like there are a lot of subqueries written in this code.

Comment: The 2 subqueries are basically types of EXISTS statements. 0= is not exists as the count will be zero if the subquery returns no records; 0<> is exists as the count will not be zero if the subquery returns any records